# gsutil not working on mac and python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to use google storage lib but I am getting an error when I call gsutil...

Installed gsutil with pip:

```
pip install gsutil
```

my current python version is `3.5`

when I run `gsutil` from command line I get the bellow error:

```
class AbortException(StandardError): NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined
```

Not sure how to workaround this issue... any ideas?

EDIT:
Looks like it works fine using python 3.4 despite they say it's not supported on 3x...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like now Python3 support exists:

`pip3 install gsutil`

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

From the [gsutil System Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install?hl=en#specifications) documentation:

> To use gsutil, you must have Python 2.6.x or 2.7.x installed on your
>   computer. gsutil does not currently run on Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Because gsutil still does not support Python 3, I decided to write a replacement: https://pypi.org/project/gs/. In addition to supporting Python 3, it can be used as a Python library, and has a few other improvements over gsutil functionality (courtesy of click, the CLI helper library).